# korean and alphabet regex returning false

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

I have been having trouble validating a form input for my website. Im looking the accept both english characters and korean characters for the name field. I had no trouble with inputting korean characters but at soon as I added the korean regex, the function has been returning false while without it returns true.

```
var recommend_coffee_your_name_field = $('#coffee_recommend_your_name_field');

recommend_coffee_your_name_field.keyup(function(e) {
  var $th = $(this);
  $th.val( $th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\u{3130}-\u{318F}\u{AC00}-\u{D7AF}]/g, function(str) { 
    alert('You typed " ' + str + ' ".\n\nPlease use only letters and numbers.'); return ''; 
  } ) );

  if(e.keyCode !== 8 || e.keyCode !== 9 ) {             
    var recommend_coffee_your_name_field_length = recommend_coffee_your_name_field.val().length;
    //console.log("Your Name Field Length: " + your_name_field_length);

    if( recommend_coffee_your_name_field_length > 0 ){
      //recommend_coffee_your_name_field.removeClass("error").addClass("success");
      recommend_coffee_shop_your_name_value = true;
    }
    else{
      //recommend_coffee_your_name_field.removeClass("success").addClass("error");
      recommend_coffee_shop_your_name_value = false;
    }
    if (!recommend_coffee_shop_your_name_value) {
      alert("The name field is missing");
      e.preventDefault();
    } 
});
```

Comment: Are you required to have the braces around the unicode values? I was under the impression that it would be, for example, \u3130 instead of \u{3130}

Comment: @adanot seems to be right : http://jsfiddle.net/9g583tfo/

Comment: -.-' it seems that adanot was right. I just tried and it seems to be working. I was under the impression that it was the right format. Thanks Kaiido for the proof. I hate regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, it is enough to remove the curly braces from the Unicode escape sequences:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]/g
```

Note that `\u{3130}` is only possible in ECMAScript 6 compatible browsers, please refer to [ECMAScript 6 Compatibility Table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

The [JavaScript String Literals Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#String_literals) calls `\uXXXX` *Unicode escape sequences*:

> The Unicode escape sequences require at least four characters following `\u`.
>   *Example*: `\u00A9` = `©`

And `\u{XXXXX}` are called *Unicode code point escapes*:

> New in ECMAScript 6. With Unicode code point escapes, any character can be escaped using hexadecimal numbers so that it is possible to use Unicode code points up to `0x10FFFF`. With simple Unicode escapes it is often necessary to write the surrogate halves separately to achieve the same.
>
> *Example*:`\u{2F804}` // The same with simple Unicode escapes: `\uD87E\uDC04`

Comment: And please do not hate regex, it is real fun :)